# remove options in my select element

Tags: jquery, html

i have the following select element:

```
<select id='payTypes'>
  <option value='1'>Cash</option>
  <option value='2'>Check</option>
  <option value='3'>Standard</option>
</select>
```

can someone show me how to remove the option **Standard** from the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery to get the payTypes `select` and the eq selector to get the third (it's zero based so i use 2) and then use the remove method: 
`$("#payTypes option").eq(2).remove()`

EDIT:

```
$("#payTypes option").each(function() {
if($(this).val() > 2) { //if it's not check or cash
$(this).remove();
}
}
```

Comment: Sheilds - Is there a way to say "if not cash or check remove from select"

Comment: @rod - you meant, it's whether selected or not. i didn't get it?

Comment: @dino beytar - no, i mean at $(document).ready i'd like to remove elements from the select list based on a condition. they are many values that list start with and i think it would be easier to say what i want in the list than what to take out of the list.